# Prove that the angle formed is 90° at a perfectly elastic collision

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

I've read the already asked questions on this but I'm still stuck:

> Prove that when 2 perfectly elastic particles collide, with one being at rest, the angle formed is 90°

**Attempt.** Given that this is perfectly elastic, the energy and the linear momentum doesn't change, and both particles being A and B, being B the one at rest initially, and being $\vec{p}$ the linear momentum before the collision and $\vec{p'}$ the linear momentum after the collision.
$$\begin{cases} \vec{p}=\vec{p'}\\ E_c(A)=E_c(A)+E_c(B)\end{cases}$$ from the first one as the $\vec{p_B}=0$ because B is at rest: $$\implies \vec{p_A}=\vec{p'_A}+\vec{p'_B}$$ $\vec{p}=m\vec{v}$ and letting both masses being $m_A$ and $m_B$ we get
$$m_A\vec{v_A}=m_A\vec{v'_A}+m_B\vec{v'_B}$$ isolating $m_A$ $$m_A(\vec{v_A}-\vec{v'_A})=\vec{v'_B}m_B$$ $$m_A=\frac{\vec{v'_B}m_B}{\vec{v_A}-\vec{v'_A}}$$ subsituting into the other equation: $$\frac12 m_Av_A²=\frac12 m_Av_A'²+\frac12 m_B v_B'²$$ $$m_Av_A²=m_Av_A'²+m_B v_B'²$$ $$m_A(v_A²-v_A'²)=m_Bv_B'²$$ substituting $$\frac{\vec{v'_B}m_B}{\vec{v_A}-\vec{v'_A}}(v_A²-v_A'²)=m_Bv_B'²$$ arranging it a bit and cancelling $m_B$ we get $$\frac{v_A²-v_A'²}{\vec{v_A}-\vec{v_A'}}=\frac{v_B'²}{\vec{v'_B}}$$ but I'm pretty much stuck here, I have also tried with the $\cos(\alpha)=\frac{\vec{v}\cdot\vec{w}}{|\vec{v}||\vec{w}|}$ but anything worked out, anyone can shine a light on this?

Comment: What do you mean when write the quotient of two vectors? Furthermore, I think the perpendicularity result you quote depends on the particles having equal mass. The dot-product of $\vec v_{A}$ with itself may be useful.

Comment: Does the quotient of 2 vectors not make sense?  And oh does it really depend on both having same mass? And with the dot product, wouldn't we be assuming what we are trying to prove?

Comment: It does not, and it's not helpful at all, since to truly make any progress on those equations you will need to break the vectors on their components. So, just do it from the beginning.

Comment: you can obtain the dot product $~\vec v_A\cdot \vec v_B\overset{?}{=}0$  you have now two components for each vector , the scalar product if general is not equal zero , you can ask the question for which start velocity components the scalar product  will be zero?

Comment: I got the answer that the component of the start velocity pint A must be $~v_{x0}=-{\frac {{v_{y0}}\, \left( m+M \right) }{-m+M}}~$ where m is the mass of A and M is the mass of B

Comment: @PedroPinhoby breaking the vectors into components you mean to do $\vec{p_A'}=(|\vec{p_A'}|\cos(\alpha),|\vec{p_A}|\sin(\alpha))$? with all of them? or with velocities?

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in the angles between the final velocities, why don't you start by breaking the momentum conservation into the x and y components? You might want to think: What are the conservation relations for each component? How the component of each particle relate to each other? Is there any way we can find the relation between the angle of each final velocity?

A interesting thing to ask yourself is: In the Center of Momentum Frame, after the collisions, the particles must go on opposite directions - after all, they were traveling in opposite directions before the collision. Then how the angles between than translate when you change from the Lab Reference Frame to the Center of Momentum Frame?

In the end, you will find that the angle between them is correlated with the ratio of their masses. The 90$^{\circ}$ angle is a special case of equal masses.

I hope that with this will help you. Feel free to ask for further help if you are stuck. For even more details on this topic, you might want to check a Classical Mechanics book like "Classical Dynamics of Particles and Systems" by Thornton & Marion.

On last thing, after you have finished this trigonometric approach to the 2D collision, you might want to check a **Non-Trigonometric Approach**. You can check it [here](https://www.vobarian.com/collisions/2dcollisions2.pdf).

Comment: If I hit a pool ball head on with the cue ball, the 'angle' between velocities is $180^{\circ}$, not $90^{\circ}$, so I don't really get the question...

Comment: Okay I will try with the components, but by breaking into components you mean $\vec{v}=(v_x,v_y)$?

Comment: @Gert, indeed this is what you get from a head on collision, that is the 1D cenario. But if this is not the case the then the angle between then is 90°. This gif might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Elastischer_sto%C3%9F_2D.gif

Comment: @PedroPinho Ok, that clarifies it. Ta.

Comment: @PedroPinho how does Wikipedia prove that it forms a right triangle? because it does not seem clear to me at all

Comment: Because it seems we are assuming what we are trying to prove? I've done with the right triangle $$90^\circ+\alpha+\beta=180$$ (total angles on a triangle) which gives $\alpha+\beta=90^\circ$ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are both the angles that form $\vec{v_A}$ with $\vec{v_B'}$ and $\vec{v_A}$ with $\vec{v_A'}$. Which concludes the proof

Comment: @Xetrex, the gif itself is not a proof. It serves to understand better the not head-on collision. For a better proof of the angle after the collision it's good the check the full article here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision

Comment: Better yet, Thornton & Marion book on Classical Mechanics will give you enough info. If you wish to skip the trigonometric approach, the link I presented in my answer will be a nice addition to the gif itself

Answer (score 1):

Breaking the vectors into components are not necessary, and may cloud the picture.

Essentially, you are trying to prove that,
for an elastic collision with two identical-mass particles with one initially at rest,
the triangle of momentum-vectors (formed from the single nonzero initial momentum vector and final particle momenta) is a [possibly degenerate] right-triangle. In particular, that the final-momentum vectors are perpendicular (have a zero dot-product).

Start with your expression:
$$m_A\vec{v_A}=m_A\vec{v'_A}+m_B\vec{v'_B}.$$
This expression (conservation of total momentum) forms a triangle.

Use my conditions and the hint in my comment.

Comment: how do you know it's a right triangle? it is not clear to me at all

Comment: @Xetrez , one does not know it at the start.  But if you say that the final velocities are perpendicular (the result you wish to show), then, if what you say is true, then the triangle must be a right triangle.  So, one could formulate a strategy based on this geometric insight.

Comment: I don't get it, it's like if we are assuming what we want to prove? You can look up my comment above where I tried going with geometry

Comment: @Xetrez, no, we are not assuming it....  we are finding a geometric interpretation of the result. We are not assuming it is true... we are saying that if the angle of the final velocities is 90 degrees, then that means we are actually dealing with a right triangle. If it's not 90 degrees, then it's not a right triangle.

Comment: @Xetrez, did you carry out my suggestions in this answer? Rather than worry about it, Just try it.

Comment: I think I have carried out your suggestions there if I think I understood you correctly, but sadly I don't *fully* see how we are not assuming what we want to show... hmmm, I will come back later, any sort of different and simpler example may help me understand why we are not assuming what we are trying to prove